# multiple img carousel displaying only one img

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to include a carousel on my website that display 3 images per time, but doesnt matter which method I use, it is only display one img per time.

http://jbm.juvoclients.com/our-projects/project1/

And I have tried 3 different links but all end up displayn only one per time.
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop

It looks like the jquery is not working.
I spent the whole day on this, butI could not find the issue.

thank you

Comment: My client request me to use visual composer, I just found out that it doesnt allow me to use any other carousel apart from the Visual composer carousel.

Comment: I just need to understand why it is now creating 2 rows